# Should I call IsDialogMessage() before TranslateAccelerator()

Tags: winapi

My main window is a modeless dialog box created with CreateDialogParam() and I need to use accelerators. Should I call IsDialogMessage() before I call TranslateAccelerator() Or is it the other way around? Which one of these 2 is correct and why?

```
if(!IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg))
{   
    if(!TranslateAccelerator(hDlg, hAccel, &msg))
    {   
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

or

```
if(!TranslateAccelerator(hDlg, hAccel, &msg))
{   
    if(!IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg))
    {   
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the MSDN sample code, IsDialogMessage() first.  If the dialog code has consumed the message then it should not be processed any further.

Comment: When I use IsDialogMessage() first accelerators don't work. hDlg is handle to main window. hDlg has a few child controls

Comment: If it works one way and not the other why are you even asking?

Comment: I wanted to understand why accelerators don't work when IsDialogMessage() is called first

Comment: Depending on your specific accelerators it could well be, that they collide with dialog navigation keys. This could be either the default dialog manager's implementation, or a control on the dialog getting greedy over keyboard input ([WM_GETDLGCODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425.aspx)). If you want to play it safe, do as Raymond Chen would: [The dialog manager, part 9: Custom accelerators in dialog boxes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/08/406509.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The thread is old, but in case somebody will be searching for the same issue, here is my take:

I needed IsDialogMessage() for some reason. However, it fully disabled all my accelerators, like F1, etc., when according to “classics” I put TranslateAccelerator() on the second position. Unfortunately, I could not solve this mystery (frankly, didn’t try hard enough; need to make a special test…) Instead I was planning to try subclassing so I could get rid of IsDialogMessage at all. But then I decided to swap the calls, et voila, everything started to work fine!

So, you can put TranslateAccelerator() before IsDialogMessage(), just make sure it does not block an important key stroke.

But the main question is still unanswered: “why accelerators don't work when IsDialogMessage() is called first?”

Comment: Your post doesn't seems to be answering the question. Please post only if you have answer to this question. Otherwise, you can ask a new question instead.